# Get first value from filtering an observable array

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Let's say I have an observable array with structure such as:

```
let arr = Observable.of([{a: null}, {a: [1,2,3,4]}, {a: [1,2,3]}, {a: null}])
```

And I want to pull out the first object where `a` is not `null`.  How can I return `{a: [1,2,3,4]}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
let arr = Observable.of([{a: null}, {a: [1,2,3,4]}, {a: [1,2,3]}, {a: null}])

arr
.pipe(
  // with this map you transform the array emitted by the source into the first item where a is not null
  map(a => a.find(item => !!item.a))  // find is the array method
)
.subscribe(
  // the data emitted here can be null if all items in the original array have an a property null
  data => console.log("I am the first item with a not null, if any", data)
)
```